# Meteor blaze ng-model equivalent for select box

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of select boxes generated from an array (from DB). 
As a simplified example:

```
Template.home.helpers({
    peers: [
            { name: "Sagar", rating: "3"},
            { name: "Sagar", rating: "3"},
            { name: "Sagar", rating: "3"},
            { name: "Sagar", rating: "3"}
        ]   
});
```

I loop through the peers array and call the following template:
HTML:

```
<template name="ratingInput">

    <div>
        <label for="{{name}}">{{name}} </label>
        <select id="{{name}}">
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose rating</option>
            <option value="1" >Still learning</option>
            <option value="2">Can Improve</option>
            <option value="3">Decent</option>
            <option value="4">Extra-ordinary</option>
            <option value="5">Should Mentor</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to bind a variable to each select box like Angular's ng-model.
Like for a textbox we can:

Can we do something like that for a select box.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a `select`, you will need to use a helper so you can perform two-way data-binding in Blaze:

```
Template.ratingInput.helpers({
  isSelected: function(v1, v2) {
    return (v1 === v2);
  }
});
```

Then you can call `isSelected` in each option to check which option should be selected:

```
<template name="ratingInput">
    <div>
        <label for="{{name}}">{{name}} </label>
        <select id="{{name}}">
            <option value="0" disabled>Choose rating</option>
            <option value="1" selected={{isSelected value "1"}}>Still learning</option>
            <option value="2" selected={{isSelected value "2"}}>Can Improve</option>
            <option value="3" selected={{isSelected value "3"}}>Decent</option>
            <option value="4" selected={{isSelected value "4"}}>Extra-ordinary</option>
            <option value="5" selected={{isSelected value "5"}}>Should Mentor</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

To modify the value when the select is modified, you'll need an event listener:

```
Template.ratingInput.events({
  'change select': function(e, t) {
    var newVal = $(e.target).val();
    // update the value here
  }
});
```

Read more about data-binding in Blaze [here](https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook-deprecated/data-binding.md)